# how to updata new item in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a new item to my list, I use firebase without user(email,password)

I want to  add new items like this:

list

- vdjs43ndjufd87

  "name" : Jak

  "university" : Harvard

list

- vdjs43ndjufd87

  "name" : Jak

  "university" : Harvard

  "age" : 23

this code is not working for me

```
let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key

let post = ["uid": userID,
            "author": username,
            "title": title,
            "body": body]
let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                    "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)`
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Does it upload to the wrong place or not at all? Also it's confusing that your data names don't match your code names you should fix that.

Comment: please add the behavior, you only said not working

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that you were allowed to add items to you database?

By default, the firebase database has a protection that you need to deactivate while you're in development if you didn't implement any connection module for the users of your app yet.

Don't forget to reactivate this protection before submitting your app though!

You can read more about rules here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/